# Using GCController with tvOS Simulator

Tags: tvos

I don't have a new Apple TV, but am working on prototyping a game for it using the simulator. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get GCController to list the Siri remote as an available controller, as the tvOS docs indicate. My list of controllers is always 0 elements long, even if I call `startWirelessControllerDiscoveryWithCompletionHandler()`.

Does anyone have any suggestion or sample code for getting input from the Siri remote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current version of the tvOS simulator apparently does not support this functionality. I was able to try my code on a friend's dev kit, and it registered the remote as a Game Controller as expected. For now, the answer appears to be "use real hardware" or "wait for an updated to the tvOS simulator".

Comment: 3 years later and the situation has not changed. You may detect that there is "some" controller of some kind, but you may not receive any signals through the .valueChangedHandler's.

Comment: another 3 years later and the situation has not changed :/

Comment: another 3 years again ..