# how to perform action based on swipe left or swipe right on Apple TV with a Siri remote? SwiftUI Xcode 13

Tags: swipe, gesture, tvos, xcode13, siri-remote

I've tried the answer provided here:
[Detect Siri Remote swipe in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59250277/detect-siri-remote-swipe-in-swiftui)
but it seems a bit like a hack, and it produces this error:

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My question is, what is the correct way to recognize a swipe gesture from the Siri remote on tvOS using swiftUI?

Many thanks in advance!